# jQuery, javascript Parse Json and keep the same index order

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I have an array generated by php like:

```
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => files/logo.png
            [time] => 23 Mar 2016
            [size] => 1.45KB
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [url] => files/print.png
            [ftime] => 23 Mar 2016
            [size] => 3.75B
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [url] => files/empty.jpg
            [ftime] => 03 Apr 2015
            [size] => 10.80KB
        )

)
```

but when I run it with json_encode and retrieve it via ajax like:

```
    $.get(files.php", {
        findFiles: "1",
    }).done(function(json) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(json);
        console.log(obj)
    }, "json");
```

I end up with:

```
{
   "files":[
      {
         "url":"files\/empty.jpg",
         "ftime":"03 Apr 2015",
         "size":"10.80KB",
      },
      {
         "url":"files\/logo.png",
         "ftime":"23 Mar 2016",
         "size":"1.45KB",
      },
      {
         "url":"files\/print.png",
         "ftime":"23 Mar 2016",
         "size":"3.75B",
      }
   ]
}
```

It always resets array starting with 0 index. Is there a way to prevent $.parseJSON from resetting  array, and keeping the same order?

Comment: You're specifying that the `files/empty.jpg` entry goes in position `0` in your php structure. Since an array is an ordered set of components, obviously it's going to be returned in that specific order. If you want to keep what you call the "same order," renumber your structure.

Comment: @J. Titus  I guess array_values will do that.